# Difference between `ACTION for CONDITION` and for `VAR(CONDITION) ACTION VAR`

Tags: perl

#### Question

What are the differences between the way these two commands process the data.

---

#### Preexample

These commands are used to create the example data

```
mkdir 1234

touch 1234/123
```

---

#### Example

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Path;

opendir my($dh),".";
for my $i (grep{ -d && /^(\d*)_\1/} readdir $dh){
rmtree $i
}
```

This removes the directory and all contents as intended.

---

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Path;

opendir my($dh),".";
rmtree for grep{ -d && /^1234$/} readdir $dh
```

This doesn't remove the directory nor gives an error

---

#### Expected behaviour

Would be to remove the directory for both.

---

#### Versions

```
perl, v5.10.0
GNU bash, version 3.2.51
```

---

#### Extra

If i replace the `rmtree` command with `print` then it prints all the folders correctly. So this may be to do with the way certain commands handle arguments and how these args are supplied by the different for types.

---

Any further information needed just ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rmtree` is not a built-in, so it does not use `$_`as the default argument if no arguments are given. You need to pass it explicitly in your second example.

```
rmtree $_ for grep{ -d && /^1234$/} readdir $dh;
```

If a CPAN module provides a function that works on `$_`, it will always state that in the documentation. That's not the case here. Also not all of Perl's built-ins do that. The documentation in [perlfunc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html) will also explicitly this for each of them.

Comment: Cheers, i thought it would be something like that but seem to have missed the obvious! Also the semi colon was a typo, sorry :)

Comment: @123 that happens to the best :)